# PC very slow with any graphics acceleration

Tags: intel-graphics

I think I don't have the correct driver for my video card which is integrated (the pc is mainly used for office work). I'm using Kubuntu 14.04.1
Each time I start any site with heavy graphics or where it requires acceleration (youtube, google maps street view, etc.) the pc is slowed to a halt nearly..

lscpi returns this:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor D2xxx/N2xxx DRAM Controller (rev 03)                     
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor D2xxx/N2xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 02)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 02)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 4 (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev e2)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation NM10 Family LPC Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 02)
01:00.0 USB controller: Texas Instruments TUSB73x0 SuperSpeed USB 3.0 xHCI Host Controller (rev 02)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 07)
```

Output of `inxi -G`:

```
Graphics:  Card: Intel Atom Processor D2xxx/N2xxx Integrated Graphics Controller 
           Display Server: X.Org 1.16.0 
           drivers: (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) 
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.0hz, 1024x768@60.0hz 
           GLX Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.5, 128 bits) 
           GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 10.3.2
```

I don't have `xorg.conf` in `/etc/X11/` and I don't know what to do.

Output of `apt-cache policy xserver-xorg-video-intel`:

```
xserver-xorg-video-intel:
  Installed: 2:2.99.910-0ubuntu1.4
  Candidate: 2:2.99.910-0ubuntu1.4
  Version table:
 *** 2:2.99.910-0ubuntu1.4 0
        500 http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2:2.99.910-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Output of `lspci -knn | grep -A2 VGA`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Atom Processor D2xxx/N2xxx Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0be2] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Pegatron Device [1b0a:013a]
    Kernel driver in use: gma500
```

Contents of `/var/log/xorg.0.log`:

http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/10620898/

Comment: Would you install `inxi` by running `sudo apt-get install inxi` and then post the output of `inxi -G`. It is a small script that summarizes system features and displays them. The option -G shows everything important about your graphics in few lines.

Comment: @ByteCommander certainly, here it is:
'Graphics:  Card: Intel Atom Processor D2xxx/N2xxx Integrated Graphics Controller 
           X.Org: 1.16.0 drivers: (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) Resolution: 1920x1080@60.0hz, 1024x768@60.0hz 
           GLX Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.5, 128 bits) GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 10.3.2'

Comment: I edited the information into your question. Are you sure it is the full output? It seems like you forgot a few words...

Comment: All I'm getting from inxi -G is:
`Graphics:  Card: Intel Atom Processor D2xxx/N2xxx Integrated Graphics Controller 
           X.Org: 1.16.0 drivers: (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) Resolution: 1920x1080@60.0hz, 1024x768@60.0hz 
           GLX Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.5, 128 bits) GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 10.3.2`

Comment: "Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe" means that your uses a pure software renderer. You should be able to resolve this with [How do I install intel integrated graphics controller?](/q/338483/175814).

Comment: @DavidFoerster I'm ready to try anything :) I will try and comment here

Comment: @DavidFoerster I added the Intel graphics card installer but it said it doesn't see my videocard (which i can understand since there isn't one). Then I installed xserver-xorg-video-intel and it is indeed installed but what to do now?

Comment: Please add relevant new information to your question (use the [edit] link below it), so other readers become aware of it. Where does your `xserver-xorg-video-intel` package come from? Can you please run `apt-cache policy xserver-xorg-video-intel` and post the output (again, [edit] your question, don't use the comments for that)? I would also like to follow the suggestion of that linked question and see the output of `lspci -knn | grep -A2 VGA`.

Comment: @DavidFoerster hopefully did it as I should (I'm new to the site, as you can see)

Comment: The driver seems to be in order. Did you reboot after installing it? What's the content of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`? Try to format the listing as a [code block](/editing-help#code) with the `<$>` button in the toolbar of the editor this time.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I'm doing what I can but the code is huge (450+ lines) and whatever I do it wouldn't format it in a pleasant manner. Should I send it to an e-mail perhaps?

Comment: For larger (log file) listings, it's best to upload them to a pastie service like http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/ and include a link to it in your question.

Comment: @DavidFoerster That's added, thank you for explaining the ways of askubuntu.

Comment: I can't find anything odd in the Xorg log. Do you get [this warning](//i.stack.imgur.com/AiwJH.png) by any chance?

Comment: @DavidFoerster Unfortunately not :( I don't get any messages or errors its just the performance of the nettop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you have a driver issue. Your problem is that you're trying to run Kubuntu, which has the highest sytems requirements of any *buntu edition, on a computer that has only an Intel Atom processor. For a normal performance on a computer with an Intel Atom processor, you should use a more lightweight *buntu edition like Xubuntu 32-bit or Lubuntu 32-bit. Xubuntu 32-bit should run fine on your computer. Lubuntu 32-bit is even more lightweight, similar in its systems requirements to Windows XP.

If you don't mind waiting until the official Ubuntu MATE 15.04 is released this April, then I will switch gears and recommend Ubuntu MATE 15.04 instead of Xubuntu because it has better default apps for what you are doing including Firefox, Thunderbird, LibreOffice, VLC, Rhythmbox and the Ubuntu Software Center. Lubuntu 15.04, Xubuntu 15.04 and Ubuntu MATE 15.04 all have similar minimum systems requirements.

Comment: Alright, so wouldn't just installing a new desktop environment do the trick (Xfce or whatever xubuntu was using).

Comment: But the `inxi` output lists no driver. That looks very strange to me. Additionally, the GLX Renderer is on "very-low-graphics" mode (llvmpipe)!

Comment: If you don't mind the extra cruft, then installing the *xfce4* package should do.

Comment: @ByteCommander It's getting its graphics processing from the same Intel Atom CPU that is already choking under the heavy processing load of Kubuntu's KDE Plasma desktop environment.

Comment: @karel if you are sure nothing else can be done ( i really like kde :) )

Comment: I'm beginning to see your point about installing a new desktop environment in stock Kubuntu. That way if you don't like Xfce, you can uninstall it and you'll still have KDE as before.

Comment: But if it is software rendering the whole stuff via CPU, then a correct driver is missing, isn't it? Or does his machine have no graphic card at all and render through the North Bridge chipset?

Comment: The Intel Atom D2700 processor (for purposes of comparison) has integrated processor graphics with a graphics base frequency of 640 MHz. See: [How do I install intel integrated graphics controller?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/338483/how-do-i-install-intel-integrated-graphics-controller).

Comment: I read somewhere that installing the correct driver might solve the issue, but you are saying the CPU actually is supposed to also do the work for graphics rendering on that pc?

Comment: Yes, I'm saying that: http://ark.intel.com/products/59683/Intel-Atom-Processor-D2700-1M-Cache-2_13-GHz To give you a concrete idea of what these numbers mean, if your Intel Atom CPU had 4 cores with same specs as the 2 cores you have in your computer, then it would run Kubuntu properly with no performance issues, so that is why your computer feels like it is running at "half speed".

Comment: @karel The processor is with 4 cores, at least according to the system monitor

Comment: No, it doesn't have 4 cores. It has 2 (physical) cores with 2 threads each for a total of 4 threads. What the System Monitor calls CPU1, CPU2, CPU3, and CPU4 are threads, not cores.

Comment: Okie dokie, I give up - Xfce here I come...

Comment: I'm afraid Xfce didn't make almost any difference. Firefox is still struggling to show a normal utube video and omg..full screen is a myth. I can't believe u need more than this configuration to run video streaming with perfect internet connection.

Comment: Now you're stuck. I was wondering how Xfce would perform as a desktop environment installed on top of Kubuntu. So far you haven't lost anything because you still have your original Kubuntu OS. At this point you have nothing to lose, so I'm going to switch gears and give you my personal opinion. The official Ubuntu MATE 15.04 release will be out this April. It is similar to Xfce because it is lightweight, but a lot better looking with better default apps (better default apps for you I mean). If you must reinstall I will recommend you install the official Ubuntu MATE 15.04, not 14.04 or 14.10.

Comment: Thank you @karel, i will hold on to kubuntu until april then :) i'm really not in the mood for one more reinstall (had to do that twice last week as in Ubuntu it was completely dead)

Comment: Please comment if/when you install Ubuntu MATE 15.04, as I'm thinking of trying Ubuntu MATE 15.04 in a virtual machine.